# How do I find out if a product can work on 240 V?

Tags: voltage, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

How do I check if a product can work on 240VAC?

For the impending winter, I bought a desk heating mat from an online seller in Australia (where mains electricity runs on 220-240VAC). I received an American plug with it which would mean the mat works on 120VAC. The mat itself has no acceptable Voltage label/markings on it. I dont have a step down transformer so this mat is pretty much useless as it stands. The return postage makes it worthless to send it back. I dont want to add to landfill. Is there a way I can find out if I can safely use this mat with an Australian IEC C7 power cable? I have a multimeter handy, if that helps.

Comment: Does the mat come with some sort of control box/brick?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy The product description says its got three levels of temperature control. So just a little plastic rectangular area (size of an average match box) on the top with a button (which I guess can be pressed a few times to adjust temperature) where the C7 cable plugs in.

Comment: You can ask the supplier ... if they are trustworthy.

Comment: Could you add a photo or two, or a link to photos?

Comment: Did you read the manual, there should be a single page at least? What about the package? Is there any information about voltage?

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds like a case of [caveat emptor](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/caveatemptor.asp). If there's a Latin phrase for "buyer beware" then, this concept/problem has existed for millennia. I guess at least you should not make the same mistake again.

Comment: "I dont want to add to landfill" Then stop buying electronics from shady online dealers selling illegal goods. Australian customs won't stop dangerous and life-threatening electronics from entering the country, but damn you if you try to enter carrying a banana. They have nice priorities like that.

Comment: _"The mat itself has no acceptable Voltage label/markings on it."_ That's a fire or electrical shock hazard waiting to happen in itself. Destined for the e-waste bin.

Comment: @Lundin that's because customs, and especially bio-security, is not trying to save people from their own stupidity. It's trying to save the country from your stupidity. And collect taxes.

Comment: most likely, a simple heating mat will deliver 4 times the heat with 2 times the voltage. This could be enough to burn you, melt itself, or start a fire.

Answer (score 7):

If it wasn't designed for use in Australia, then as a rule of thumb it isn't safe to use (and therefore illegal to sell in Austrialia). If it was designed for use in USA then the product is likely designed for 120VAC @60Hz whereas the Australian power grid uses (around) 230VAC @50Hz.

You cannot "measure" any of this with a multimeter. Any AC/DC regulators, diodes, capacitors etc inside will be rated for the expected voltage and fail in case they are wrong, or cause the product to dangerously misbehave or catch fire etc.

The only way to check this, short of reverse-engineering everything on the component level, is if there is labeling claiming it suitable for 230VAC @50Hz or similar guarantees made by the manufacturer.